Отображение информационного блока на странице в Битрикс
Всем привет. Есть инфо блок "контакты", в котором имеются просто контакты (элементы) и разделы (папки, в которых контакты объединены по группам). Сейчас у меня все элементы выводятся, как будто деления на разделы нет. Как сделать так, чтобы контакты из раздела (папки) отображались в одном <div class="st-qa__item">...</div>, а не в разных
<?php if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();
/** @var array $arParams */
/** @var array $arResult */
/** @global CMain $APPLICATION */
/** @global CUser $USER */
/** @global CDatabase $DB */
/** @var CBitrixComponentTemplate $this */
/** @var string $templateName */
/** @var string $templateFile */
/** @var string $templateFolder */
/** @var string $componentPath */
/** @var CBitrixComponent $component */
$this->setFrameMode(true);
?>

<?php if (!empty($arResult['ITEMS'])): ?>

    <?php foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $arItem): ?>

        <div class="st-qa__item">
            <div class="st-qa__item-title">
                <span><?= isset($arItem["NAME"]) ? $arItem['NAME'] : ''; ?></span>
                <div class="st-qa__item-icons">
                    <div class="st-qa__times d-none">
                        <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <line x1="10.3536" y1="9.64645" x2="30.1525" y2="29.4454" stroke="#CE4C21"/>
                            <line x1="9.64645" y1="29.6464" x2="29.4454" y2="9.84746" stroke="#CE4C21"/>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="st-qa__plus">
                        <svg width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 28 28" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <line x1="14.5" y1="-2.18557e-08" x2="14.5" y2="28" stroke="#CE4C21"/>
                            <line y1="13.5" x2="28" y2="13.5" stroke="#CE4C21"/>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="st-qa__content">
                <p class="st-qa__p"><?= isset($arItem["DETAIL_TEXT"]) ? $arItem['DETAIL_TEXT'] : ''; ?></p>

                <?php if (!empty($arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"])): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach ($arItem["DISPLAY_PROPERTIES"] as $arProperty): ?>
                            <li><?= $arProperty["NAME"] ?>: <?= $arProperty["DISPLAY_VALUE"] ?></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/header.php");


$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Контакты");
use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;

Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/css/contacts.css");
Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/css/qa-page.css");

?><!-- BEGIN DESKTOP VERSION -->
<section class="contacts-section">
<style> 
    span.op {
        border-top: dotted 1px white;
        padding-top: 7px;
        <!-- color: #b74620; -->
    }
    .txttohtmllink {
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>
    <!-- BEGIN MAIN -->
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- BEGIN TITLE -->
            <div class="main-container">
                <div class="contacts__title-container">
                    <h1 class="contacts__title">Контакты</h1>
                    <div class="contacts__qa">
                        <div class="st-qa">

                            <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:news.list", 
    "career.list", 
    array(
        "CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",
        "CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
        "CHECK_DATES" => "Y",
        "DETAIL_URL" => "",
        "DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PREVIEW_TEXT" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_TOP_PAGER" => "N",
        "FIELD_CODE" => array(
            0 => "",
            1 => "",
        ),
        "FILTER_NAME" => "",
        "HIDE_LINK_WHEN_NO_DETAIL" => "N",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "22",
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "contacts",
        "INCLUDE_IBLOCK_INTO_CHAIN" => "N",
        "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "N",
        "MESSAGE_404" => "",
        "NEWS_COUNT" => "20",
        "PAGER_BASE_LINK_ENABLE" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING" => "N",
        "PAGER_DESC_NUMBERING_CACHE_TIME" => "36000",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALL" => "N",
        "PAGER_SHOW_ALWAYS" => "N",
        "PAGER_TEMPLATE" => ".default",
        "PAGER_TITLE" => "Новости",
        "PARENT_SECTION" => "",
        "PARENT_SECTION_CODE" => "",
        "PROPERTY_CODE" => array(
            0 => "DOLZNOST",
            1 => "TITLE",
            2 => "PHONE",
            3 => "FAX",
            4 => "NAME",
            5 => "EMAIL",
            6 => "TOWN",
        ),
        "SET_META_DESCRIPTION" => "Y",
        "SET_STATUS_404" => "N",
        "SORT_BY1" => "SORT",
        "SORT_BY2" => "SORT",
        "SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
        "SORT_ORDER2" => "ASC",
        "STRICT_SECTION_CHECK" => "N",
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "career.list",
        "AJAX_MODE" => "N",
        "ACTIVE_DATE_FORMAT" => "d.m.Y",
        "ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN" => "Y",
        "AJAX_OPTION_JUMP" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_STYLE" => "Y",
        "AJAX_OPTION_HISTORY" => "N",
        "AJAX_OPTION_ADDITIONAL" => "",
        "CACHE_FILTER" => "N",
        "CACHE_GROUPS" => "Y",
        "PREVIEW_TRUNCATE_LEN" => "",
        "SET_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SET_BROWSER_TITLE" => "Y",
        "SET_META_KEYWORDS" => "Y",
        "SET_LAST_MODIFIED" => "N",
        "DISPLAY_DATE" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_NAME" => "Y",
        "DISPLAY_PICTURE" => "Y",
        "SHOW_404" => "N",
        "TEMPLATE_THEME" => "blue",
        "MEDIA_PROPERTY" => "",
        "SLIDER_PROPERTY" => "",
        "SEARCH_PAGE" => "/search/",
        "USE_RATING" => "N",
        "USE_SHARE" => "N"
    ),
    false
);?>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="contacts__content">
                    <div class="contacts__wrapper">
                        <div class="contacts__top-block">
                            <div class="contacts__address-title">
                                681000, Россия, Хабаровский край, г. Комсомольск-на-Амуре, ул. Вагонная, 30
                            </div>
                            <a class="show-on-map" target="_blank" href="https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCUB6QHdhA" title="Показать на карте">Показать на карте</a>
                            <svg class="map-dot" width="61" height="62" viewBox="0 0 61 62" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <circle opacity="0.5" cx="30.5248" cy="31.2636" r="30.4155" fill="url(#paint0_radial_1194:493)" />
                                <circle cx="30.5257" cy="31.2637" r="4.74054" fill="#EA5E20" />
                                <defs>
                                    <radialGradient id="paint0_radial_1194:493" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(30.5248 31.2636) rotate(90) scale(30.4155)">
                                        <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
                                        <stop offset="0.0001" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
                                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.19" />
                                    </radialGradient>
                                </defs>
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contacts__bottom-block">
                            <span>50.55794707500202, </span>
                            <span>136.95876408937576</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- END TITLE -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MAIN -->
</section>
<!-- END DESKTOP VERSION -->



<? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/bitrix/footer.php"); ?>


Вынесете за пределы цикла этот див

попробовал - неполучилось, а можно чуть подробнее?

Div перенесите между if и foreach и закрывающий не забудте
